# Error on Info window with button, when I add polygon

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, infowindow

I wan to execute a Infowindow with button, its execute nicely. I use [this](https://github.com/codexpedia/android_google_map_custom_marker), where I found on github.

But, if I try to put GeoJson layer on it, the button is disapear

I try many way to make this error gone, but I still facing problem with this.

[This Error I found, the button is disapear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQQir.png)

[This is what I want, with GeoJson layer on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3XRx.png)

Here's my Main Activity

```
ublic void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CILACAP, 10f));

    mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);

    // MapWrapperLayout initialization
    // 39 - default marker height
    // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
    mapWrapperLayout.init(mMap, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

    // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
    // so let's create only one class member instance
    this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
    this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    this.infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

    // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
    // so it shows up
    this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_normal),
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed)) {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tombol " + marker.getTitle() + " di click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent pdf = new Intent(MainActivity.this, showPdf.class);
            pdf.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
            startActivity(pdf);
        }
    };
    this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
            infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            //infoImage.setImage(marker.getMarker());
            infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

            // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
            // to the MapWrapperLayout
            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
            return infoWindow;
        }
    });

    // Let's add a couple of markers
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Kecamatan Adipala")
            .snippet("Kecamatan Adipala")
            .position(ADIPALA)
            .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.iconbuilding))
    );

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Kecamatan Bantarsari")
            .snippet("Kecamatan Bantarsari")
            .position(BANTARSARI).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.iconbuilding))
    );

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Kecamatan Binangun")
            .snippet("Kecamatan Binangun")
            .position(BINANGUN)
            .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.iconbuilding))
    );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Kecamatan Cilacap Utara")
            .snippet("Kecamatan Cilacap Utara")
            .position(CILACAPUTARA).icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.iconbuilding))
    );

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks